# Ubuntu 16.10: Install Office 2010 with playonlinux

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-office, wine

In attempting to install MS Office Professional Plus 2010 on Ubuntu 16.10 via Playonlinux, I've encountered the following issue.  For reference, I am using a 32-bit installation file I downloaded (i.e., not a CD) and the default settings in Playonlinux.  However, after extraction, I get the following log output:

```
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
[POL_Wine_OverrideDLL] Message: Overriding DLLs
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.7.52 regedit /home/mariustor/.PlayOnLinux//tmp/override-dll.reg (Working directory : /home/mariustor/.PlayOnLinux/shortcuts)
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
[POL_Call] Message: Calling POL_Install_msxml6
[POL_Call] Message: ----- Starting function POL_Install_msxml6 -----
[POL_GPG_auth_script] Message: Checking signature of POL_Install_msxml6
[POL_GPG_install_key] Message: Importing PlayOnLinux public key
[POL_Source] Message: POL GPG : Good signature
[POL_Download_Resource] Message: Downloading resource http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/a/f/eafb8ee7-667d-4e30-bb39-4694b5b3006f/msxml6_x86.msi
[POL_Download_Resource] Message: Resource already present
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.7.52 msiexec /i msxml6_x86.msi /q (Working directory : /home/mariustor/.PlayOnLinux/ressources)
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
[POL_SetupWindow_detect_exit] Warning: POL_SetupWindow_detect_exit is deprecated
cat: /home/mariustor/.PlayOnLinux//configurations/guis/3427: No such file or directory
[POL_Call] Message: ----- Ending function POL_Install_msxml6 -----
[POL_Shortcut] Message: Looking for <WINWORD.EXE>, found <>
wrestool: /home/mariustor/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
wrestool: /home/mariustor/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./: Is a directory
icons-brut: premature end
[POL_Shortcut] Error: Binary not found: WINWORD.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```

The installation terminates in an error on the last two lines of this output.

**Question is: what's causing this installation to blow up and how can I work around it?**

Comment: I recently had a smooth experience with Office Professional 2010 32-bit on Linux Mint Mate; did you successfully install the Plus version previously or is this your first try? It looks like `WINDORD.EXE` cannot be found, can you confirm it is there, or possibly try with a new ISO?

Comment: This is a new ISO.  I have installed this previously, albeit on a different machine, and it was quite smooth as you say.  Hence why I'm puzzled as to what's going on here.

Comment: Just realized that I didn't answer the full question in your comment: I cannot find WINWORD.EXE, let alone any other Office-related program in ~/.PlayOnLInux/wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c and its subfolders.

Comment: I undestand. Will need to setup a Ubuntu 16.10 test machine to see whether this can be reproduced.

Comment: Ach -- forget it.  Error is between chair and keyboard.  I forgot that the *.exe that I downloaded isn't a setup file...it's a self-extracting repository.  Once I extracted the repo and tried again, using the executable inside of the extracted files, it installed just fine.  Thanks for checking in, though.

Comment: Great, so it was a problem with the ISO not being an ISO :-) For completeness' sake one of us should post an answer and then you should accept it to mark this issue as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the executable that I downloaded wasn't an iso.  That initial file was a self-extracting repository that, once extracted, *then* provides the necessary installation files in the extracted folder.  Playonlinux installed Word, Excel, and Powerpoint smoothly and all three programs have been working well since that revelation.

Answer (score 1):

Some people say these are workarounds:

- Used a 32 bit prefix (64bit would crash because of a missing dll)
- Installed msxml3, msxml6, riched30, ie8 with winetricks
- Copied following dlls:

  ```
  drive_c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/ClickToRun/AppvIsvSubsystems32.dll
  drive_c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/ClickToRun/C2R32.dll
  ```

  and pasted them in

  ```
  drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/
  ```

  where the applications are located, though others claim they should be moved to

  ```
  drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Client/
  ```

  instead.
- With Wine regedit:

  ```
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Direct2D] add "max_version_factory"=dword:00000000
  ```